# Outlook 2016 Item List Format

Tags: ms-office

I recently upgraded from Outlook 2011 to Outlook 2016.  I'm quite irritated that with the Reading Pane on the right (how I had it setup with 2011) that each message in the Item List takes up 3 lines.  If you hide the Reading Pane, or place it on the bottom, then each message only takes up one line.  I want the Reading Pane on the right, and the messages to only take up one line, but I cannot seem to find the right settings to achieve this.  Can anyone suggest how to make this work?

Comment: At the very bottom of that article, it says "Applies To: Outlook for Mac 2011".

Comment: Oh, whoops - sorry :)